# Will CPU mining cause high power consumption?

Tags: mining

I have an AMD FX 6300 and i'm using VirtualBox to assign two cores and mine. I get around 100h/s, however, will this cause a much higher energy consumption and a higher electricity bill?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It will cause more electricity usage. How much electricity depends on several factors such as the number of threads used, which you noted. The only way to know for sure is to measure the electricity usage at the wall with a device like a "Kill A Watt" meter. Measure the watts being used while the computer is on but not mining. Then measure the amount of watts used while mining on one thread, then with two threads, up to the total number of threads your CPU supports. The difference of those measurements will tell you how much electricity the computer uses while mining on the different number of threads.

From those measurements you can determine which mining arrangement gets you the most hashes per watt. You will want to take measurements incrementally with each thread because, depending on the system, 2 threads may be more efficient than 3 threads. Or, 6 threads may be more efficient than 8 threads, and so on.

Also keep in mind that mining will create heat and this could increase your need for air conditioning, and that will add to your costs. One CPU won't make much of a difference...maybe 1 to 3 degrees F in a bedroom, but your results may be different.